# Jenkins: Agent's Job execution does not recognize neither Maven nor Gradle for "Execution Shell"

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

For Jenkins for *Controller* and *Agent* configuration, the connection from to the former to the latter works as expected.

The Agent is **Ubuntu Desktop** 18, it has `Java`, `Maven` and `Gradle` *installed* manually through `.tar.gz` and `.zip` files. They are configured in the `~/.profile` file. It is confirmed as follows in the Ubuntu's terminal:

```
which java
/opt/java/openjdk/jdk-11.0.12+7/bin/java

which mvn
/opt/apache/maven/3.8.2/bin/mvn

which gradle
/opt/gradle/7.2/bin/gradle
```

In the Controller was created a simple Job to be executed in the Agent based with *shell script*

Therefore an *Execute shell* is added as follows:

[image]

When the Job is executed at the Agent, it fails with:

```
$ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins264232505144646074.sh
which java
/usr/bin/java
java --version
openjdk 11.0.11 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
which javac
javac --version
/tmp/jenkins264232505144646074.sh: line 17: javac: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Well, the solution is add in the Agent in its configuration in the `Node Properties - Tool Locations` section the following:

[image]

It works fine:

```
/bin/bash /tmp/jenkins9449416287517820673.sh
which java
/opt/java/openjdk/jdk-11.0.12+7/bin/java
java --version
openjdk 11.0.12 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.12+7 (build 11.0.12+7, mixed mode)
which javac
/opt/java/openjdk/jdk-11.0.12+7/bin/javac
javac --version
javac 11.0.12
```

**Note**: both the Controller and Agent have the same JDK version, same as Maven and Gradle.

Until here all fine. Now for Maven and Gradle.

For Maven

[image]

But the Job fails with:

```
$ /bin/bash /tmp/jenkins7864398981124864641.sh
...
which mvn
mvn --version
/tmp/jenkins7864398981124864641.sh: line 12: mvn: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Observe `mvn: command not found` - So, in the `Node Properties - Tool Locations` section
is added:

[image]

But again the Job fails with the same error message.

Even adding in `Node Properties - _Environment variables_` as follows

[image]

the Job fails with the same error message.

The same situation happens with Gradle

**Note:** In the `Controller`, the `Agent` was *Disconnected* and *Re-Launched* for each addition in the `Node Properties` section configuration to apply the new settings.

So how fix this situation?

Comment: Configure Maven/Gradle via global tools configuration

Comment: @khmarbaise why worked for Java and not for them? - Yes, I have the 3 declared on `Global Tool Configuration` - but the paths are based on the `Controller` PC - the settings for `Node Properties` are for the `Agent`

Answer (score 1):

As @khmarbaise said, configure Maven and Gradle via *Tools configuration* as well.

Jenkins launches agents using *non-interactive shell*, so does not source `~/profile`, only `/etc/profile`. Must configure the rest in *Tools Configuration* as you did w/JDK.

[Custom Tools](https://plugins.jenkins.io/custom-tools-plugin/) plugin or [Extra Tool Installers](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extra-tool-installers/) plugin may help if you have to add other custom tools.

But, if you are using the UI, then why not use an invoke maven step and install [gradle](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle/) plugin as well? Don't use a `sh` step down there's a wrapper available.

Comment: Yes, I have the 3 declared on `Global Tool Configuration` - but the paths are based on the `Controller` PC - the settings for `Node Properties` are for the `Agent`

For the `Custom  Tools` plugin - it has the `This plugin is up for adoption! ` message - so is safe use it?

I am not using the plugins for Maven and Gradle because I use _script shell_ (.sh) for them

Comment: Why the configuration worked for Java and not for Maven and Gradle? They are in the same section - `Node Properties - Tool Locations` section

Comment: That would probably be because whereas "JDK" is global to the Job (hence its option in "General" tab of the job, whereas Maven and Gradle are intended for use with a "Invoke top-level Maven step" or "Invoke Gradle script" step. This is similar to [ant](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ant/) and [NodeJS](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodejs/), except both those have been extended to a similar global to the Job option as the JDK. Not sure the range "Custom Tools" or Extra Tools Installer" have.

Comment: As for the path to the tools, you can either have a global setting that is common path everywhere or override at the Node level: "Tool configuration".

The Custom Tools plugin is "Up for adoption", but was written by a Cloudbees employees, is relatively current and has no issues, so is as safe as can be. Consider too, [Extra Tool installer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extra-tool-installers).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - About - `Jenkins launches agents using non-interactive shell` just being curious - is there an official link that indicates that explicitly? - I will do a research about how in linux (Ubuntu) would be possible use some script file to solve this situation

Comment: I understand you are using an 'sh' step, just not sure why; it's obviously more difficult if you don't work with the plugins. You could also consider a pipeline over Freestyle.

Comment: re: "is there an official link that indicates that explicitly?"

"When the SSH Build Agents plugin connects to a agent, [it does not run an interactive shell](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-slaves-plugin/blob/master/doc/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#login-profile-files)" is about as official as it gets.

Comment: Huge thanks for your polite support! - time to do more research :)

Comment: I solved this - due `Jenkins launches agents using non-interactive shell` situation, in the `Execute shell - Command` now is defined manually/explicitly the `. /home/jenkis/.profile` execution and done. With this new addition the `Node Properties - Tool Locations` now is empty - I prefer keep and configure these settings through the Agent side through the `.profile` file.